# Multi Window is not working

Tags: android, multi-window

I am currently trying to implement the Multi Window Feature to my Application.

I followed [this guide](http://www.modaco.com/page/news/_/android/developers-add-support-for-samsung-multi-window-to-your-apps-r823).

And here is my Problem:

I added the following lines to the manifest

```
        <intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
```

and

```
    <uses-library required="false" name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow"> </uses-library>
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_W" android:value="632.0dip" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_H" android:value="598.0dip" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.MINIMUM_SIZE_W" android:value="632.0dip" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.MINIMUM_SIZE_H" android:value="598.0dip" />

    </application>
```

I get this Error

```
 Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix
```

in this line:

```
    <uses-library required="false" name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow"> </uses-library>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing this line

```
<uses-library required="false" name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow"> </uses-library>
```

to this line:

```
<uses-library android:required="false" android:name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow"> </uses-library>
```